# How to use swagger to describe a form with a file and filename

Tags: swagger

I would like to create a http form that contains two input fields: file, fname where the file is of type file and the fname is text (the name of the uploaded file.)  The form is going to send the results to a node application.  In swagger something like this:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  title: Test
  description: Tdesc
  version: "1.0.0"
host: localhost:8080
schemes:
  - http
basePath: /v1
produces:
  - application/json
paths:
  /fileup:
    x-swagger-router-controller: Default
    put:
      operationId: fileupPut
      consumes:
        - multipart/form-data
      parameters:
        - name: fname
          in: formData
          required: false
          type: string
        - name: file
          in: formData
          required: false
          type: file
      responses:
        200:
          description: D
          schema:
            type: string
```

I copied this to the http://editor.swagger.io/#/ and then exported it as a nodejs program and ran the program.  Visit http://localhost:8080/docs to use the swagger generated UI to "put" the file, fname.  I put a breakpoint in the generated Default.js controller and noticed that the file and fname is undefined.

```
 module.exports.fileupPut = function fileupPut (req, res, next) {
   var file = req.swagger.params['file'].value;
   var fname = req.swagger.params['fname'].value;
   ...
```

I understand that file handling code (like busboy) can be used to stream to a file.  I do not understand how swagger parsing can be used to get the strings for file and fname.